# how to avoid other git local repository projects be recognized as unstaged changes?

Tags: reactjs, git

Recently I was building a very basic react projector for learning reasons and I faced with a very annoying problem described by theses logs:

```
 npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! react-tutorial-guide@0.1.0 eject: `react-scripts eject`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the react-tutorial-guide@0.1.0 eject script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-09T22_43_29_500Z-debug.log
```

I did a quick search, spent a lot of hours I finally I found the problem.
There was some unstaged change in my projects so I should do:

```
git add .
git commit -am "some message"
```

to solve the problem, I did it and in the principle, the problem wasn't been solved. I saw more carefully my project and I could see that git local repositories outside my react projects folder was been considered as unstaged changes. So when I try to commit my project by the commands above, it failed and consequentially the problem wasn't been solved what doesn't make sense they were outside my project folder and I was inside my project folder when I executed the git commands to solve the problem.

I investigated more carefully to solve the problem, so I noted that My reacts project is inside a folder, where there is other react projects, and this React projects folder was inside the document user folder, to be more precise in this path on my os system (windows 10): C:\Users(USER_NAME)\Documents

To solve the problem I simply deleted the folder where there were local git repositories and finally I could execute the wanted task:
npm run eject

I know this solution is very bad, but it was the only one that I was able to do and it is too annoying because it will cause me future problem in the react projects where I have to execute

```
npm run eject
```

in my projects when it were needed. I'm finding a better solution and if someone could show me how to avoid this issue I would be too thankfully.

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-09T22_43_29_500Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is not a problem with git. The error which you got is probably because of the way that you have installed the node or npm in your system. Maybe by updating the npm would have also solved your problem.

```
npm install -g npm
```

You can also download the latest version of node.js from the [official site](https://nodejs.org/en/).

There is an another way of updating the node through node version manager(nvm). Please follow the [instruction](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md) for installing or updating the nvm.